# CSV parsing for Shopify

Tags: php, laravel, csv, phpexcel

**What I have:**

A laravel application that parses a user's CSV file. The data in the file includes one field with HTML code in. It is encapsulated by ".

Some rows don't have tags. I target the rows that have tags and I save a variable with the row number so that I can edit it later.

E.g. `Item 837, Description, "<h1>HTML code</h1><br/><h2>eh<h2>", Some Other Data, "Tag 1"`

I'm using http://maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel which uses PHPExcell

**My problem**

1. Shopify requires all the fields NOT to be enclosed in double quotes; only for the HTML code and the tags field.
2. when I parse the array, at every \r\n \n found in the HTML code, it would jump into a new array entry.

**What I want**

Parse the CSV data to come out as an array like

```
[id] => 12,
[tags] => "tag 1, tag 2",
[body] => "<html></html>",
[variable] => description text,
```

when I export, I want data to appear like so in the notepad

`12, "tag 1, tag 2", "<html></html>", description text,,,,,,,,`

**What I have tried**

1. Set LaravelExcell enclosure to *nothing* which resulted in chaos. Whenever there's a linebreak (LF) in the HTML code, the parser would jump into a new line.
2. Tried using file_get_contents and str_replace to replace \r\n to empty so that LaravelExcel wouldn't jump around like crazy. Didn't work out since I needed the format of the HTML to stay the same.
3. Tried using `Config::set('excel.csv.enclosure', '"');` on import, and `Config::set('excel.csv.enclosure', '');` on export. Export file is all messed up.

Comment: Try loading it into an array via `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));`  Should be easier to work with.

Comment: The \r\n still makes the line in the html field to jump onto the next array. It's really annoying me.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Products API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product)?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to continue using the PHPExcel to parse the CSV data as it provided an organizable array using line enclosure `"` and delimiter of `,`.

However, on exporting the file, I ditched the PHPExcel class and instead used fopen() and fwrite() to parse everything in the array to the format of Shopify/csv. *with lots of preg_match & if statements such as if a field contained a comma, it'd enclose it with `"`*.